# Method not found in protocol: Objective C

Tags: objective-c, protocols

I have this in my view controller:

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] sendMessageAsSingleObject:[sender currentTitle]];
```

Which gives me this warning:

```
warning: '-sendMessageAsSingleObject:' not found in protocol(s)
```

But in my AppDelegate i have the method declared in the header...

I should add that the call works, just want to get rid of the warnings.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]
```

Returns an object that implements the `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol. This protocol doesn't have the method `sendMessageAsSingleObject`. So your compiler doesn't know that this method is actually there. You need to cast the delegate first to the specific class of your application delegate.

```
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate sendMessageAsSingleObject:[sender currentTitle]];
```